# How to format facebook status retrieved using status.get

Tags: facebook

When I retrieve my facebook status through facebook API, using status.get, the informations comes in the form of

```
[
  {
    "message": "Does anyone here knows how to disappear and reappear again after a few months??",
    "time": 1282146230,
    "status_id": 00000000000000,
    "source": 2915120374,
    "uid": 000000000
  },
  {
    "message": "Blah blah and blah",
    "time": 1282073572,
    "status_id": 00000000000000,
    "source": 2915120374,
    "uid": 000000000
  }
]
```

I want to format the information using css and display the updates on my blog. How do I extract the info from the above retrieved format so that I can use it on my php page and use css to style the updates??

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: This does belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As noted by others, this is a programming question (about JSON if I'm not mistaken) and should be directed at StackOverflow.com.